# Livewire folder structure

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am quite new to Livewire and I feel a little bit confused about its folder structure.

I use the classic Laravel folder structure for my views and I put the components under the `/resources/views` folder; now with Livewire it seems that I am forced to put my components under `/resources/views/livewire` folder otherwise the component throws an error.

I also tried to change the view_path in my `config/livewire.php` file to `resource_path('views')`, instead of `resource_path('views/livewire')`, but it doesn't work.

The result is a messy structure like the following, where the users' components are in a different folder and I have to go back and forth to find what I want.
Wouldn't it be possibile to remove the `/resources/views/livewire` folder and put the components under the relative folder they belong to?

- resources

  - views

    - users

      - index.blade.php
    - livewire

      - users

        - table.blade.php

Comment: Is it really a problem? To be it looks logical: regular Blade files are in resources/views and Livewire files are in resources/views/livewire, and the components could be loaded in the main Blade files. Since Livewire components are just "helper" files and not the main Laravel layout, I like the fact they are separated.

Comment: It's not a problem, but it looks quite messy to me. I would like to have the components and the views of the users inside the users folder. It seems to me like I'm duplicating things. I would accept a livewire folder inside /resources/views/users

Comment: well that's not how Livewire works, Livewire doesn't know your folder structure so it works by its own structure. Technically you could probably make it work like you want but it would require a lot of overriding the defaults every time, for no particular reason except that you want it different than how everyone else use it.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is the config file /config/livewire.php

```
'view_path' => resource_path('views/livewire'),
```

Just make sure you update all the Livewire class files views in their render function and that you clear any stale config information

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

edit: I have tested this and have regular Laravel blades along side livewire ones.